# Using a Tkinter Optionbox to carry out a MySQL query

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I am trying to use a tkinter option menu to select the variable to search for in a table. A problem arises however as the passed variable does not yield any result.

Here is the table: [image: table]

And here is proof that the SQL syntax is not incorrect.
[image: Proof Of SQL]

The problem is due to the string variable being incorrect and returning:

```
[]
```

no data.

When I select a variable from the OptionMenu, instead of getting:

```
jhgfds
```

I get:

```
('jhgfds',)
```

So understandably I get no result.

I have tried using these methods on the :

- Creating a non-tkinter variable (`StrEditEvent)
- The `re` method
- The `[2:-3]` method

However these have not worked

```
import tkinter as tk
import mysql.connector
root=tk.Tk()
EventList=[]

def OptionChanged(*args):
    EventSQL=("SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventname=%s")
    print(EditEvent.get())
    StrEditEvent=EditEvent.get()
    print(StrEditEvent)
    mycursor.execute(EventSQL,(StrEditEvent,))
    myresults=mycursor.fetchall()
    print(myresults)

# Adding Tracking Variable EditEvent
EditEvent = tk.StringVar()
EditEvent.trace("w", OptionChanged)
#Connecting To My Database
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="Cranmore1",
    database="scoutsdatabase"
)
print(mydb)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT eventname FROM events")
myresults=mycursor.fetchall()
for i in myresults:
    EventList.append(i)
EventToEditOptionMenu = tk.OptionMenu(root,EditEvent,*EventList)
EventToEditOptionMenu.grid(row=1,column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> print(EventList)
>
> ```
> [('jhgfds',), ('uytrds',), ('sadfghjk',), ('jhytre',), ('j',), ('h',), ('q',), ('BBC',), ('BBC',), ('qwed',)]
> ```

Comment: May I see the output of `print(EventList)`

Comment: You may: `[('jhgfds',), ('uytrds',), ('sadfghjk',), ('jhytre',), ('j',), ('h',), ('q',), ('BBC',), ('BBC',), ('qwed',)]`

Comment: it returns the result as `tuple` so unless you iterate over it.

Comment: Change to `for _tuple in myresults: EventList.append(_tuple[0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally worked out the answer! To obtain the string from the tuple, one must use the `map()` command.

```
def OptionChanged(*args):
        EventSQL=("SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventname=%s")
        StrEditEvent=EditEvent.get()
        start,mid,end=map(str,StrEditEvent.split("'"))
        print(mid)
        mycursor.execute(EventSQL,(mid,))
        myresults=mycursor.fetchall()
        print(myresults)
```

Thus `('jhgfds',)` is converted into `jhgfds` so the SQL query finds the data from the database.

Answer (score 1):

To get the result as `jhgfds` you need to iterate over it because it returns the result for the query as a tuple `[('jhgfds',), ('uytrds',), ('sadfghjk',), ('jhytre',), ('j',), ('h',), ('q',), ('BBC',), ('BBC',), ('qwed',)]`

You can use index to get the specific result you want `result[0]` or `result[2]`

```
def OptionChanged(*args):
    EventSQL=("SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventname=%s")
    print(EditEvent.get())
    StrEditEvent=EditEvent.get()
    print(StrEditEvent)
    mycursor.execute(EventSQL,(StrEditEvent,))
    myresults=mycursor.fetchall()

    for result in myresults: # iterate over it
        print(result)
        print(result[2])
        print(result[5])
```

Comment: @MainStreet if the answer solves your problem make sure you tick it as reference for future programmers

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution does not work as you've neglected to notice that no results were being created in the current state of the program. Thanks for your efforts anyhow.